# php email sending application form

Tags: php, email

How do I make an application form in PHP that sends an e-mail using the `mail()` function?

Answer (score 2):

PHP mailing at its simplest.

```
<?php

$message = "This is my e-mail message.";

mail('recipient@example.com', 'Message subject', $message);

?>
```

The PEAR packages [`Mail`](http://pear.php.net/package/Mail) and [`Mail_Mime`](http://pear.php.net/package/Mail_Mime) have a lot of useful features for sending mail, as well. Take the user's input, build a message, and send it along. Beyond that, we'll need to know what you're having trouble with.

Answer (score 1):

A very simple contact form may look like this. Note that this is simply for a demonstration. I wouldn't suggest using this as-is:

```
<?php

  // If our form has been submitted
  if ($_POST["submit"]) {
    // Gather up some values
    $name   = $_POST["username"];
    $msg    = $_POST["message"];
    $errors = false;
    // If the name and message aren't empty
    if (!empty($name) && !empty($msg)) {
      // Email them to ourselves
      mail("me@mydomain.com", "Website Email", "{$name} says: {$msg}");
    } else { // If they are empty
      // Set an error message
      $errors = "Please fill out the form.";
    }
    // If we have errors as this point, show them
    if ($errors) print "<p>".$errors."</p>";
  }

?>
```

```
<form method="post">
  <p>Name: <input type="text" name="username" /></p>
  <p>Message: <textarea name="message"></textarea></p>
  <p><input type="submit" name="submit" /></p>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Tak a look at the http://swiftmailer.org/, using mail() function without proper data escaping could be very vulnerable for attacks and custom headers injection.